# Find and update multiple Json data in one column using Laravel and Eloquent

Tags: json, laravel, eloquent

How can I search for a particular "checkNo" and get the value, then update it.

Here is my query that I am using to get the data, but it returns empty:

```
$isUpdate=DB::table('transactions')->whereIn('pdc_data->checkNo', [35343])->get();

[
{
    "calD": "--", 
    "date": "12-02-2019", 
    "Int": "3500", 
    "amount": "20166.666666666668",
    "finInt": "403.33333333333337",
    "checkNo": "35343",
    "remarks": "--",
    "bankName": "Fugit eius aut voluptatem fugiat delectus soluta.",
    "accountNo": "3353", "branchName": "Aut velit qui qui ut."
},
 {
    "calD": "--",
    "date": "12-17-2019",
    "Int": "3500",
    "amount": "20166.666666666668",
    "finInt": "403.33333333333337",
    "checkNo": "35344",
    "remarks": "--", 
    "bankName": "Fugit eius aut voluptatem fugiat delectus soluta.", 
    "accountNo": "3353", "branchName": "Aut velit qui qui ut."
}, 
{
    "calD": "--",
    "date": "01-01-2020",
    "Int": "3500",
    "amount": "20166.666666666668",
    "finInt": "403.33333333333337", 
    "checkNo": "35345", 
    "remarks": "--",
    "bankName": "Fugit eius aut voluptatem fugiat delectus soluta.",
    "accountNo": "3353", "branchName": "Aut velit qui qui ut."
}
]
```

Comment: have you try this
`$isUpdate=DB::table('transactions')->where('checkNo', "35343")->update(['remarks'=>'Good'])`

Comment: this will not work because  the "checkNo" is in pdc_data

Comment: @DebasisBhakat  How to generate JSON data?

Comment: @AmitSenjaliya i did't get you question correctly?

Comment: @DebasisBhakat Above JSON data availble on `$pdc_data`  variable?

Comment: `pdc_data`  is row name in MySQL

Comment: @DebasisBhakat `pdc_data` is row name or column name??

Comment: @AmitSenjaliya sorry it's column name.

Answer (score 0):

In order to search in a json colum and use multiple parameters you have to use:

```
->whereJsonContains('pdc_data->checkNo', ["35343"])
```

This is the equivalent of the `whereIn` clause

Also in your json column you are having a `string` value for this field but you are trying to pass an `int` so you get no results back cause there is no matching in the variables type.

Just a side note, if you want this field to actually hold an integer value, make sure to store it as an integer so you can check it across same type values.

Checking a string against an integer, or treating an integer as a string can lead you to issues.

Comment: i also use this but this return me a empty array

Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
        )

)

Comment: try with simple checkNo field not pdc_data->checkNo

Comment: And this set of Json is store in one column.

Comment: "try with simple checkNo field not pdc_data->checkNo"
it's say's  Unknown column 'checkNo'

Comment: I know where your error is. You are passing an int but in your db it is a string. that's why it fails/ i will update my answer.

Comment: i am using this query  `$isUpdate=DB::table('transactions')->whereJsonContains('pdc_data->checkNo', ["35343"])->get();`
and still got an empty array.

Comment: which laravel verison are you using?

Comment: i am using laravel 5.8

Answer (score 0):

You need to decode JSON and then match your query.

You should use `transactions` table column name in `whereIn('column name', '45464')` clause.

```
$data = json_decode($pdc_data, true);

for($data as $value){
     $isUpdate=DB::table('transactions')->whereIn('Yourcolumn name', $value->checkNo)->get();
}
```

Comment: i am sending only the `checkNo` not a full json data set